# Python Outlook extract mails by Date Range gives a fixed lower limit, irrespective of User Input

Tags: python, outlook, mapi

This is a bit hard to explain but let me try !!!

I tried reading Outlook Mails using Python (MAPI) and every time I give a Date Range with the code:

```
.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Start_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + End_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"
```

For Example range is : All mails from `2019` to `2020`.

But the output is surprisingly, from `25/06/2019` to whatever the upper user limit is.
No matter what, lower limit I give, it always throws up mails from `25/06/2019`.
And today it is throwing up mails from `26/06/2019`.

Hence, it might be some internal setting which makes it output mails from exactly one year ago.

There is no resource on Google for this exact issue, hence stackOverflow is the last hope.

(Also, for example: Range from `2019/01/01` to `2019/06/26` gives me mails for only 26th.

I've tried this on other Outlook accounts but the result is identical.)

Comment: What is the actual filter string?

Comment: `.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Start_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + End_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"`

Comment: Not really sure what U wanted to know but the above string is the filter string in my code

Comment: What is the actual string after evaluating parameters and formatting?

Comment: So the Restrict line gives a `<COMObject Restrict>` after which I have a `for` loop `for inbox in COMObject: inbox.SenderName; inbox.Subject` etc

Comment: I hope I could answer your question.

Comment: How is the actual search string looks like after evaluating parameters and formatting?

Comment: And `Start_user_input` is just a `str(userInput)` same with `End_user_input`

Comment: What is the actual parameter passed to the `Restrict` method?

Comment: [ReceivedTime] ?

Comment: `"[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Start_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + End_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'"`

Comment: Are we giving `Restrict` the wrong parameters ?

Comment: What is the actual string after concatenating all params?

Comment: Okay I think I understood what U mean. We don't have any other string, this is it, we wrote the Restrict criteria directly inside the Restrict Function.

Comment: I have seen online that people make filters first and then pass the filters to the Restrict Function but we directly wrote it inside.

Comment: So this is the complete code: `inboxmessages = inbox.items;                                                    inboxmessages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]" ,True; X = inboxmessages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + Start_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + End_user_input.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + "'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve all Outlook items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to sort the items in ascending order:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics
' ...
Private Sub RestrictCalendarItems(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim dtEnd As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, _
                                         DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 0, 0)
    Dim restrictCriteria As String = "[Start]<=""" + dtEnd.ToString("g") + """" + _
                                     " AND [End]>=""" + DateTime.Now.ToString("g") + """"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim appItem As Outlook._AppointmentItem = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim item As Object = Nothing
   
        strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        folderItems = folder.Items
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        folderItems.Sort("[Start]")
        resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria)
        item = resultItems.GetFirst()
        Do
            If Not IsNothing(item) Then
                If (TypeOf (item) Is Outlook._AppointmentItem) Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    appItem = item
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                          " Start: " + appItem.Start.ToString() + _
                                          " Subject: " + appItem.Subject + _
                                          " Location: " + appItem.Location)
                End If
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
                item = resultItems.GetNext()
            End If
        Loop Until IsNothing(item)
        If (strBuilder.Length > 0) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " _
                             + folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If   
End Sub
```

In your case, you need to call the `folderItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")` method.

Comment: Did that `inboxmessages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]" ,True)`

Comment: Does ascending , descending make a difference ?

Comment: I tried with `.Sort("[ReceivedTime]")` but still only received emails from `2019-06-26`

Comment: Do you see older items in Outlook?

Comment: Hi @Eugene, I feel embarrassed to say this but our Organization had limited the number of mails to one year, hence the output from the code.

Comment: The code is working Fine !!! Now trying to convert numeric user input to corresponding month and output all mails from only that month. For ex: `user_input = 1` ; input to `Restrict(January 1st to 31st)`.